# PayPal Integration and payment status in react native

Tags: paypal, react-native, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to integrate PayPal as a payment method in my react-native app. I get an access token by hitting `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` API, but when I'm trying to pass access token to payment API  `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment` got response with status code 400 or 500 both are varying.

My code is

```
  let currency = '100 INR'
currency.replace("INR", "")

const dataDetail = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": currency,
            "currency": "INR",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": currency,
                "tax": "0",
                "shipping": "0",
                "handling_fee": "0",
                "shipping_discount": "0",
                "insurance": "0"
            }
        }
    }],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "https://example.com",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com"
    }
}
fetch('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
         'Accept': 'application/json', 
         'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('AUrtJxcHfMUlDjHgV2FHMOUnzMkUeu86_km7h67uEHzH5b5RN7Vo-q8AYPtcdz7Iaioc46xW0H9JQZmT:EMbbJ-YqQLT6liuPtJURq2pAgh9WuUTDKmV355_VIeADst0BMlnUNKiHVLK7itCyZFXrEQOex9p93WO8')
    },
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(async (data) => {
    console.log(data.access_token)
    this.setState({accessToken:data.access_token})
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(dataDetail))
    fetch ('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
    {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+(this.state.accessToken)
        },
        body:dataDetail
    }
)
    .then(response => {
        console.log('response=====',response)
        // const { id, links } = response.data
        // const approvalUrl = links.find(data => data.rel == "approval_url")

        // this.setState({
        //     paymentId: id,
        //     approvalUrl: approvalUrl.href
        // })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log({ ...err })
    })
}).catch(function (error) {
    let edata = error.message;
    console.log('Error:', edata)
}
)
```

Any one can help please ?
response

```
 {"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "f2d967a5-2700-4f03-b2ac-2e4ec22f10e4", "offset": 0, "size": 232}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "f2d967a5-2700-4f03-b2ac-2e4ec22f10e4", "offset": 0, "size": 232}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"cache-control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate", "content-language": "*", "content-length": "232", "content-type": "application/json", "date": "Tue, 23 Feb 2021 07:20:25 GMT", "paypal-debug-id": "27bb91ae40c3a"}}, "ok": false, "status": 400, "statusText": undefined, "type": "default", "url": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment"}
```

reference Link [PAYPAL INTEGRATION IN REACT-NATIVE](https://medium.com/zestgeek/paypal-integration-in-react-native-9d447df4fce1)

Comment: "got response with status code 400 or 500 both are varying." Post the full response JSON data in your question if you want help

Comment: posted please help @PrestonPHX

Comment: What you added is the response object, not very useful. You need to get the text() of it, or json() and then re-stringify.  Also helps to log the request's data in case there's some discrepancy between it and what you're expecting your code to send.

Comment: Posted response as it is in JSON

Comment: No, that is the response object, it is not the JSON data. Anyway, updated answer below with this logging added and 2 issues solved

Answer (score 0):

> https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

`v1/payments` is a [deprecated API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1). You should integrate the current v2/checkout/orders instead.

[Here is some documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) -- you want "Create Order" and "Capture Order" API calls.

---

But, if you want to understand the problems with your v1 code, here they are fixed and with proper request+response data logging

Issues:

- `currency` variable wasn't being set to a valid number w/o spaces
- You need to JSON.stringify() your request body.

```html
<script>
let currency = '100 INR';
currency = currency.replace("INR", "").trim() ; //this was a problem line, replace() is not in-place. And also extra space to trim
let accessToken = '';

const dataDetail = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "total": currency,
            "currency": "INR",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": currency,
                "tax": "0",
                "shipping": "0",
                "handling_fee": "0",
                "shipping_discount": "0",
                "insurance": "0"
            }
        }
    }],
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "https://example.com",
        "cancel_url": "https://example.com"
    }
}

fetch('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', { 
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
         'Accept': 'application/json', 
         'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('AUrtJxcHfMUlDjHgV2FHMOUnzMkUeu86_km7h67uEHzH5b5RN7Vo-q8AYPtcdz7Iaioc46xW0H9JQZmT:EMbbJ-YqQLT6liuPtJURq2pAgh9WuUTDKmV355_VIeADst0BMlnUNKiHVLK7itCyZFXrEQOex9p93WO8')
    },
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(async (data) => {
      console.log(data.access_token)
      accessToken=data.access_token

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(dataDetail))

    let createRequest = {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+(accessToken)
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(dataDetail)
    }
    console.log('Request body string',createRequest.body);
    console.log('Request body (formatted)', JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(createRequest.body) ,null,4) );
    fetch ('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',createRequest
)
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('Response object', response);
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(async(data) => {
        console.log('Response data',data);
        console.log('Response data (formatted)', JSON.stringify(data,null,4) );
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log({ ...err })
    })
}).catch(function (error) {
    let edata = error.message;
    console.log('Error:', edata)
})
</script>
```

Comment: while changing v2 status code 404 page not found

Comment: v2/payments is not a thing, except for refunds and such. You need to integrate v2/checkout/orders

Comment: v2/payments/payment does not exist, therefore 404. To use v2/checkout/orders you need to use a different endpoint and different request syntax.